# How to make self-registering COM server (exe) with C++

Tags: c++, com

I'm a complete beginner in COM and in the process of grasping ins and outs of it.
Right there is a problem I'm trying to solve (it's a part of my test assignment).

What I need to do is make a self-registering exe COM server in native C++, i.e. an executable that will register some COM-object on execution. Most of examples I find tell of implementing server in dll and using regsvr32 on it, but I need exactly self-registering exe.

Can someone explain how do I do that?

UPD: Okay, a little more: it doesn't work. Here's a snippet:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IClassFactory *factory = new ISimpleServerFactory();
    DWORD classToken;

    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    CoRegisterClassObject(
        IID_ISimpleServer, 
        factory, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
        REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, 
        &classToken);

    ISimpleServer *pISimpleServer = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_CSimpleServer, 
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
        IID_ISimpleServer,
        (void **)&pISimpleServer);         //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< FAILS

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        printf("Instantiation successful\n");

    if(pISimpleServer != NULL)
        pISimpleServer->Release();

    std::cin.ignore();
    CoRevokeClassObject(classToken);
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is CoRegisterClassObject succeds, but CoCreateInstance tells me that object is not registered. What did I do wrong? (I unified code into same module for debugging 'cause it didn't work in different apps).

UPD2: Peter Huene helped with this one - had to use CLSID instead of IID. Now it works in-process. But when called out-of-process (from standalone client) CoCreateInstance never returns. Why could it be?

Comment: It depends on what kind of registration you are looking for.  There are at least two possibilities. Registering an active COM object for access while it is already running, and registering a COM object so that it auto-runs if it is not already running. What are you looking for exactly? Please provide more details about your requirements.

Comment: Well, in general my task sounds like "Create two console apps - server and client. When server is run, register COM server (unregister on exit). Client must utilize implemented COM object upon execution.". Just like that.

Comment: That does not clarify the issue. "Client must utilize implemented COM object upon execution" could go either way. If you only register the server COM object while the server is running, then you must run the server first or the client will fail. But if you register the server COM object statically, the OS can auto-run the server when the client needs it, and then terminate the server when the client is done with it. So again, you need to be more explicit about your requirements on both sides.

Comment: Manual run is assumed. (I translated problem by memory, it is pretty explicit in fact)

Comment: Every out-of-proc COM server calls `CoRegisterClassObject` during initialization. That is enough for the client calling `CoCreateInstance` to discover an already-running instance of the server. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I haven't done any COM in years, but CoRegisterClassObject takes a CLSID as the first argument, not an IID. I doubt your CLSID and IID are the same.

Comment: I'll check it not. BTW, could you explain me the difference? UPD: Yes, it helped. Thank you.

Comment: A CLSID (Class ID) represents the ID of the class itself.  An IID (Interface ID) represents the ID of an interface.  A COM object (an instance of a class) may expose many interfaces, each with their own identifiers (IUnknown being the only required interface to be considered a COM object).